# In the week or without a preposition

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct ?

> It was the week of your birthday when Tom went to Paris.
>
> It was in the week of your birthday when Tom went to Paris.

However, there is one more alternative

> Tom went to Paris in the week of your birthday

But I want to emphasize the time so I prefer the first example
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The preposition you're looking for is "[during](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/during)".

> It was *during* the week of your birthday **that** Tom went to Paris.

Note that it should be "that" not "when". This sentence order is a bit odd but it'd be considered acceptable.

In your second phrasing, you might alternatively consider using "over" instead of "in".

> Tom went to Paris over the week of your birthday.
>   Tom went to Paris during the week of your birthday.

That being said, you don't really need either of them in this construction:

> Tom went to Paris the week of your birthday.

Though this lacks total clarity... it could simply mean that he departed sometime during that week but not that he was gone for the entire week.

Another way you could say it is

> Tom was in Paris the week of your birthday.

This is clear, concise and means that he was gone that entire week. All of the options above are good for your example, though.

Comment: Bryan Adams would be just one of many who'd take issue with this - are you seriously suggesting he "should" have sung  [*Back **during** the summer of '69?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f06QZCVUHg)

Comment: It's a specific idiomatic usage to say "back in"... "Back in my youth..." "Back in my day". This is not that usage.

Comment: Catija, actually I just meant to say that he went to Paris sometime during the week of your birthday rather than whole week. So from my understanding if I use "during", it will mean entire week so how to say to mean "sometime in a week"? According to your example, Tom went to Paris the week of your birthday is correct form. But what about using "in" preposition?

Comment: @Melih After thinking about it, I think that with your phrasing, during still works. To make it even more clear you could say something like *It was during the week of your birthday that tom **left** for Paris*.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Catija's correct answer:  "In the week of ..." is not *incorrect*, but it can add a kind of "storytelling" nuance.  For example:

> The pilgrimage was to take place in the week before the first autumn rains, but when these came early, it had to be delayed until almost the first week of winter.
>
> In the week of Jan 20th of that year, four strangers came to town, each from a separate direction.

Also, "in" a period is time is slightly different from "during" a period of time.  During is more *precise* language to indicate the action began and ended within that time frame.  "In" instead is more vague and can indicate just the starting (or ending) point of that action.

> Trump formally began his political campaign **in** mid-June 2015.  It was **during** the summer of the next year that suspicions first arose about his possible connection to Russia.

As Catija mentions, in all these examples "in" is optional, although it sometimes does help the sentence flow better.